# Can I use wxpython to create a lot of buttons using iterations?

Tags: wxpython

```
import wx

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title='test', size=(505,500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        test = []

        for i in range(1,11):
            test.append(i)

        print(test)

        self.button1 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[0]), pos=(0, 0))
        self.button2 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[1]), pos=(100, 0))
        self.button3 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[2]), pos=(200, 0))
        self.button4 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[3]), pos=(300, 0))
        self.button5 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[4]), pos=(400, 0))
        self.button6 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[5]), pos=(0, 50))
        self.button7 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[6]), pos=(100, 50))
        self.button8 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[7]), pos=(200, 50))
        self.button9 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[8]), pos=(300, 50))
        self.button10 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label=str(test[9]), pos=(400, 50))
        self.button11 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label='...', pos=(0, 100))
        self.button12 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label='...', pos=(100, 100))
        self.button13 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label='...', pos=(200, 100))
        self.button14 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label='...', pos=(300, 100))
        self.button15 = wx.Button(self.MainPanel, label='...', pos=(400, 100))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I want to make multiple `wx.button`. The problem is that I want to create a button based on the value of the loop and give a value to the generated button label. I wonder how I can create this effectively.

Do I have to create the `wx.button` variables one by one, just like the code I uploaded as examples? Or I want to know if I can make it into a loop.

Comment: You could easily make a `list` of `wx.Button` objects, are you asking how to do that?

Comment: Yes, it is............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is not to just create lots of buttons but to make them usable as well.
In that you must be able to identify them, if they are clicked on.
You also have to be able to position them.
Here is `one` way that you can do it.
I am using a `sizer` to place them and assigning an Identity with `wx.NewId` to each button.

```
import wx

class MainFream(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None,title='test', size=(505,500), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        self.MainPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        test = []
        button_id = []
        for i in range(1,21):
            test.append(i)
            button_id.append(wx.NewId())

        self.button = []
        for i in range(len(test)):
            self.button.append(wx.Button(self.MainPanel,button_id[i],label=(str(test[i]))))
            self.button[i].Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButton)

        sizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(0, 5, 5, 5)
        for i in self.button:
            sizer.Add(i, 0, wx.ALL, 0)
        self.MainPanel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def OnButton(self, event):
        Id = event.GetId()
        Obj = event.GetEventObject()
        print ("Button Id",Id)
        print ("Button Pressed:",Obj.GetLabelText())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    fream = MainFream()
    fream.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]